# How to call UIView method from another ViewController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have implemented freehand sketch tutorial from

```
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_freehand-drawing/.
```

I need to call its `- (void)drawBitmap;` `- (void)drawBitmapGreen;` methods in my View controller for color change on button action. I have done something like below.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "checklistController.h"
@interface SmoothedBIView : UIView

@property(nonatomic,assign) checklistController *trnsferColor;
- (void)drawBitmapGreen;
@end

@implementation SmoothedBIView

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self drawBitmapred];
    [self drawBitmapGreen];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [path removeAllPoints];
    ctr = 0;
}
- (void)drawBitmapGreen
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    if (!incrementalImage) // first time; paint background white
    {
        UIBezierPath *rectpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
        [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
        [rectpath fill];
    }
    [incrementalImage drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    [[UIColor greenColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    incrementalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //SmoothedBIView.trnsferColor = self;
}
```

...

```
 @interface checklistController :   UIViewController

 @property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *vPaintPreview; //SmoothedBIview outlet for hidden and unhidden property.
 @property(nonatomic,assign) SmoothedBIview *SBIView;
-(IBAction)editvImage;
-(IBAction)RedSketch;
-(IBAction)GreenSketch;
```

**Updated code**

```
@implementation file

-(IBAction)GreenSketch
{
    SmoothedBIView *SBIview = [[SmoothedBIView alloc] init];
    [SBIview drawBitmapGreen];
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: take a view assign your class to it make its property then call its method using that property

Comment: why you used like this (`SmoothedBIView *SBIview = self;`)?

Comment: @ML: I saw this kind of method in one weblink. yes this is wrong and crashing the code:(

Comment: I have updated the Button action code. But it is not giving me desire result.

Comment: Try to put some breakpoints ,, and see the debug way that what is exactly missing..

Comment: Yep it is getting called. there is problem in - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self drawBitmap];
    [self drawBitmapGreen];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    [path removeAllPoints];
    ctr = 0;
}

Comment: This is wrong OOP design. You can pick your nose and you can pick your friends. But you cannot pick your friend's nose. Calling method on another controller's view couples your code and increases cost of maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
-(IBAction)GreenSketch
{
    SmoothedBIView *SBview = [[SmoothedBIView alloc] init];
    [SBview drawBitmapGreen];
    [SBview setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: see my - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event code. Here it need some tweak...

Comment: I place differen buttons for different colour in ViewController and gave methods for that colours in UIView class. But on red button action drawBitmapRed as well as touchesEnded method getting called with producing green colour. Do I need to change question?